# How can I refactor ruby code that calls different functions but does the same thing with their responses?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the method I was to refactor. What is a good way to refactor this code?
Is there any way to put the method calls in a list and return as soon as one of the method returns a valid response?

```
  def method
    response_hash = method1
    return response_hash if response_hash.present?

    response_hash = method2
    return response_hash if response_hash.present?

    response_hash = method3
    return response_hash if response_hash.present?

    response_hash = method4
    return response_hash if response_hash.present?
  end
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate but I will still add the relevant question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414640/ruby-call-list-of-methods-until-one-returns-true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you want to return the first non-empty result.

```
def my_method
  [:method1, :method2, :method3, :method4].each do |method_name|
    result = send(method_name)
    return result if result.present?
  end
end
```

Symbols / `send` are here to maintain the lazy nature of evaluations (don't evaluate more than necessary)